# What word did I learn today?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, english, poetry

Today I added a word to my vocabulary which is best described with a riddle:

```
Born during the second's reign whose life ended to the lance
For centuries I was used to transport mail or dress for any circumstance

I was reborn anew from an egg's observation for a rhyme yet unraveled
To help a girl born from song, not sung, during her odyssey untraveled

Monosyllabic, I am not, for I am comprised of three
A wine, a beau, then a sequel too are what my sounds should be
```

What word did I learn today?

Update: Lines 5 & 6 added as an additional hint

Comment: Since a **word** /phrase of English **language** is sought, those two tags are apt and needed, I feel.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Fair enough point and I've updated the tags, though the word isn't of English origin.  The first line provides the hint to what language it's derived from.

Comment: for transporting mail? (although perhaps chainmail)

Comment: @Jasen Yup, even mail.  Check the [wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau_%28disambiguation%29), as this word has a bit of split personality...  Normally I wouldn't link the answer in a comment, but since it has already been solved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> portmanteau.

Born during the second's reign whose life ended to the lance
For centuries I was used to transport mail or dress for any circumstance

> As @Drt mentioned, this refers to King Henri II, who reigned in the early-to-mid 1500s. The first known use of the word was in 1553, and it referred to a type of carrying case (literally, "to carry a cloak").

I was reborn anew from an egg's observation for a rhyme yet unraveled
To help a girl born from song, not sung, during her odyssey untraveled

> This refers to Humpty Dumpty from Through the Looking-Glass, where Lewis Carroll reinvented the word to refer to a linguistic blending of two words.

Monosyllabic, I am not, for I am comprised of three
A wine, a beau, then a sequel too are what my sounds should be

> PORT + MAN + TEAU

Comment: Would you have got it without the added lines?  I suspect they made this too obvious.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I was pretty sure of the literary connection, but I couldn't pinpoint the correct word until the phonetic help. I guess I didn't realize that word existed before LC.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling about this...

> King Henri II was killed from a lance run through his head/eye.

He lived from 1519 to 1559.

In that time the King would be dressed by his

> Varlet who was also often responsible for delivering messages (mail) etc.

The last two line of the riddle make me think of a different usage of the term

> Varlet

Which caused me, in my early days to think that the term meant "a dishonorable man"...The story came about because of a story I was told about a woman who killed a

> Varlet

because he killed her prize egg laying hen and then made her cook it for him for his supper...

Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: You're on the right track, but this isn't the answer.  Definitely worthy of an up-vote because you properly identified the clue provided by the first line.

Comment: I added an additional set of lines to the riddle.  Hopefully that helps get you the rest of the way there!

Answer (score 2):

I have two ideas, so at least one is wrong, probably both! However I propose:

> PATENT

because:

> The patent system was invented in the reign of Henri II. "Letters patent" and "patent leather" are both things.

Alternatively:

> COURIER

because:

> It's a French word for a message transporter, and your message is written in New Courier font.

Comment: Neither are correct, but the second was quite familiar with what I am.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is

> ARMOUR

As,

Born during the second's reign whose life ended to the lance

For centuries I was used to transport mail or dress for any circumstance

> During the King Henri II's times, an armour parade was getting conducted (a kind of practise)and an armour can be used to protect men (especially during sword fighting / fencing / lance fight  and generally in warfare), also a kind of mail (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(armour) ).

I was reborn anew from an egg's observation for a rhyme yet unraveled

To help a girl born from song, not sung, during her odyssey untraveled

> Though, not sure, an egg's shell protects the life/ yet to born animals  and similarly an aromour protects the body of the person who wears it.
>  Not sure about the last part, though!

Comment: I like the commonality you've identified, but this is not the correct answer.